# Setting the main window as a dialog owner (message box) called from a STA thread

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading

This is a function that calls a custom C# message box. The function is called from a simulation process that runs inside a thread that is not the UI thread.

```
public Output.ButtonResult msgboxYesNo(string Text, string title) {
    Output.Message_Box msg = new Output.Message_Box();

    msg.Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(() => {
        msg.seeQuestion(Text, title);
        msg.Topmost = true;
        Application.Current.MainWindow.Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(()
                          => { msg.Owner = Application.Current.MainWindow; }));
        msg.ShowDialog();                
    }));

    return msg.result;
}
```

The problematic line is this one:

```
Application.Current.MainWindow.Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(() =>
                              { msg.Owner = Application.Current.MainWindow; }));
```

And it throws this:

> The calling thread cannot access this object because a different
>   thread owns it

Because I want to set the main window as the owner of the custom message box, which is called within a separated thread.

How can I set the main form as the owner of the message box?

(I hope I explained the issue clear enough, the forms are WPF)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Output.Message_Box` is an UI component so it should be created from UI thread only and not from background thread.

**Problem in your code -**

`msg` is `created on background thread` but you are trying to `access it from UI thread` here

```
msg.Owner = Application.Current.MainWindow;
```

Instead you should even `create message box on UI thread only`:

```
Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(() =>
{
    Output.Message_Box msg = new Output.Message_Box();
    msg.seeQuestion(Text, title);
    msg.Topmost = true;
    msg.Owner = Application.Current.MainWindow;
    msg.ShowDialog(); 

    return msg.result;               
}));
```

Also you are trying to access `MainWindow` from background thread which is created on UI thread.
You can get UI dispatcher like this if app launched from main thread only: `Application.Current.Dispatcher`.

Comment: Thanks for the enlightment, I have it clear now!, I would add that I could not make a return inside the dispatcher and I had to make a variable asignment and then the return outside it.